# How to update cursor limit for ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceed

Tags: oracle11g

I have found my max number of cursors per database to be 300 from the following query:

```
select max(a.value) as highest_open_cur, p.value as max_open_cur
  from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$parameter p
  where a.statistic# = b.statistic# 
  and b.name = 'opened cursors current'
  and p.name= 'open_cursors'
  group by p.value;
```

I tried to update the amount to 1000 with this:

```
  update v_$parameter
  set value = 1000
  where name = 'open_cursors';
```

But I am seeing this error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02030: can only select from fixed tables/views
02030. 00000 -  "can only select from fixed tables/views"
*Cause:    An attempt is being made to perform an operation other than
           a retrieval from a fixed table/view.
*Action:   You may only select rows from fixed tables/views.
```

What is the proper way to update the open_cursor value? Thanks.

Comment: The limit of 300 is **per connection**, it's not an upper limit for all connections together. In most of the cases this error message indicates a sever bug in your appliction because it does not release resources properly. You should fix the problem in the application (the root cause), not fight the symptom.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a spfile to start the database

```
alter system set open_cursors = 1000 scope=both;
```

If you are using a pfile instead, you can change the setting for the running instance

```
alter system set open_cursors = 1000
```

You would also then need to edit the parameter file to specify the new `open_cursors` setting.  It would generally be a good idea to restart the database shortly thereafter to make sure that the parameter file change works as expected (it's highly annoying to discover months later the next time that you reboot the database that some parameter file change than no one remembers wasn't done correctly).

I'm also hoping that you are certain that you actually need more than 300 open cursors per session.  A large fraction of the time, people that are adjusting this setting actually have a cursor leak and they are simply trying to paper over the bug rather than addressing the root cause.

Comment: Thanks. I upped it to 3k and am still exceeding the max open_cursors. I'm not creating any cursors explicitly, so I'll have to look into the code as to why it is generating so many. There are a couple prepared statements and results sets open at the same time, but they are all closed eventually so I don't think it is a leak.

Comment: @yellavon - If we're talking about a Java application when you're talking about `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` objects, I'll happily wager that you are not closing everything correctly every time.  I'd put a large wager down that the Java application is leaking cursors and that you'll need to debug that issue.

Comment: I believe everything is closing because when I run this method on a smaller dataset, it works fine and the value of open cursors current is the same before and after on the smaller dataset. I do however have nested PreparedStatements: `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); while (rs.next()) { long seqNum = rs.getLong(1); ps1.setLong(1, seqNum); ps1.close; } ps.close;`

Comment: Good call on the leaking cursors :P The code was reusing `PreparedStatements` so it made it hard to tell what was going on. Is that a good idea, creating a `PreparedStatment`, generating a `ResultSet` with it, closing it, and then reassigning the `PreparedStatement` with completely different query? I just made it so that the `prepareStatement()` method was only called once on a `PreparedStatement` and all `PreparedStatements` and `ResultSets` were closed.

Comment: What's the maximum value ?

Comment: @AdiC.N. - 4294967295 in Oracle 10.1.  If you're thinking of setting a value anywhere near this, however, I'd strongly urge you to reconsider and to find the underlying cursor leak.

Answer (score 4):

RUn the following query to find if you are running spfile or not:

```
SELECT DECODE(value, NULL, 'PFILE', 'SPFILE') "Init File Type" 
       FROM sys.v_$parameter WHERE name = 'spfile';
```

If the result is "SPFILE", then use the following command:

alter system set open_cursors = 4000 scope=both; --4000 is the number of open cursor

if the result is "PFILE", then use the following command:

```
alter system set open_cursors = 1000 ;
```

You can read about SPFILE vs PFILE here,

http://www.orafaq.com/node/5

Answer (score 0):

you can update the setting under init.ora in
oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\config\scripts

Comment: Increasing open_cursors is a **horrible** idea. I've yet to see an application that actually needs 300 open cursors. All you are doing by increasing the value, is delaying the problem, not solving it. Almost certainly a cursor leak.

Comment: @BobC What If we are talking about multiple applications sharing one database instance? There are legitimate reasons to increase the limits.

Comment: @charlie_pl Nope! This is a per session parameter.

Comment: @BobC Obviously you haven't used ArcGIS. :)